# What does "well-swilled" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

The [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/bald-faced) has an example sentence:

> I lost track trying to count the sheer bald-faced, brazen, **well-swilled** out-and-out lies being palmed off as fact or being suggested for our consumption as reasonable readings of the text.

It appears *well-swilled* should be synonymous with other adjectives in the lineup, but I can't find this word in dictionaries. Another [example](https://www.christianitytoday.com/ct/1994/december12/4te003.html) I found:

> Our sixteenth-century forebears used adjectives such as "shameless, fat, **well-swilled**, stinking, papistical … ," as historian Timothy George wrote on our May 16 editorial page.

*Swill* means *to drink, wash, rinse*. But what does "well-swilled" mean here? Urban Dictionary has an entry that suggests it means "intoxicated". This definition does not appear to sufficiently fit the above sentences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone swills their drink, they're sloshing it around (often in their own mouth). As gargling is to the throat, swilling is to the mouth. If a lie is "well-swilled", it's been rolled around in the liar's mouth thoroughly before being spat out on you.

Comment: So, what does that implies then? *it's been rolled around in the liars mouth thoroughly before being spat out on you.*

Comment: That the liar has prepared or practiced the lie thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that "well-swilled" implies "well prepared", "well practiced" or "well used", as in the lies have been used before and roll off the tongue easily.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would say that **well-swilled** means "well-drunk."

It's being used metaphorically, and pairs with the later use of **consumption**.

In other words, the lies, like drink or food, have been accepted and taken as part of some people's intellectual "diets."

---

There is an idiom that says, **don't drink the Kool-Aid.** It's become popular as a way of saying that you shouldn't "blindly follow" someone or something.

It does have a serious origin, however, as described in the Mental Floss article ["The 35th Anniversary of the Jonestown Massacre"](http://mentalfloss.com/article/13015/jonestown-massacre-terrifying-origin-drinking-kool-aid):

> . . . Jim Jones ordered Temple members to create a fruity mix containing a cocktail of chemicals including cyanide, diazepam (aka Valium—an anti-anxiety medication), promethazine (aka Phenergan—a sedative), chloral hydrate (a sedative/hypnotic sometimes called "knockout drops"), and most interestingly . . . **Flavor Aid**—a grape-flavored beverage similar to Kool-Aid.

While it might be common to associate *well-swilled* with beer, there could also be this Kool-Aid association, and the author is making reference to a well-drunk Kool-Aid of lies.

Comment: +1 I would agree, but would add that the adjective is very contrived, an attempt to be clever.